# php curl - send post values (with header: location)

Tags: php, post, curl, header

is the first time that I compile with a curl: i'm trying to use it to send post values with header. i did many tests, but probably I mistake something because I in output don't see my post vars.

form page:

```
<html>
  <form action="analize.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="people" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
</html>
```

analize.php:

```
<?php
$url = 'test.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'analize.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);

curl_exec($ch);
$post = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($post);
?>
```

Comment: So, what happens is, you do a curl request to test.php, with a proper `POST` (which works), and then you force the client to do a GET request (without any `POST` values). What do you think `test.php` should show on that `GET`?

Comment: a GET request? i'm sorry... but where do you see it?

Comment: `header('Location: ' . $url);` => makes the user do a `GET` request.

Comment: I put that header to load the "target" test page. If I remove it the redirect does't work. Do you know a hint to solve it?

Comment: probably there is a method, to convert the POST values in GET values with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$post_vars");`... but the security?

Comment: Take a couple of steps back: you want to POST to some page, _and_ you want the user redirected to that page: what is it you're trying to achieve with this? 'cause this might not be it (you can't force a client to POST for instance).

Comment: I understood, it's impossible. I'll opt for input values via POST, and  a $Session message as result (just to see if the query works or not). thank you very much Wrikken